# Is there a way to open .exe file extensions on Chrome OS without developer mode or exe-opening apps?

Tags: chromebook

I have a Chromebook on which Linux Beta 2.0 is disabled by the administrator and there is no other way to open .exe. Any tips?

Comment: Go speak to your administrator for access.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [App on fly](https://app.apponfly.com/trial) to open executebles on your ChromeOS device

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160267)

Comment: Thank you. It worked (until I ran out of free trials).